# Why is FileStream and CopyFile so much slower than Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, copy, filestream, performance, file-copying

I'm trying to a copy a file across a network (Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows 7 SP1 Enterprise) and when I drag-and-drop using Windows Explorer, I'm getting about 4.5 MB/s.  (It's a WAN connection)

However, when I use FileStream.Read(), I'm only getting around 1.5 MB/s.  I've tried different buffer-sizes ranging from 1 KB to 4 MB.  I've also tried using CopyFile() and CopyFileEx() but I am getting the same results.

What might be going on here and how can I fix my code?

EDIT: I've also tried using TeraCopy (3rd party tool) and it is also only getting 1.5 MB/s.

Comment: Can we assume large single file?

Comment: Yes, it's a single 2.9 GB file.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/02/04/2826167.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link!  According to the information, the Vista SP1 improvements were also implemented for CopyFileEx which I'm using...

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you are still experiencing this issue or not, but I have been wrestling with this issue for days so I thought I would post this. I finally found a solution that is up to par with the Explorer copy routine. I do not know if this works for `FileStream`, but I **was** able to use `CopyFile` or `CopyFileEx` to get the same performance. In my case, `CopyFileEx` was a better choice because I wanted a progress callback. After using Process Monitor to examine the copy process, I noticed that the system was resetting the stream position (even though it hadn't moved) before *every single* read and write operation for each 32k chunk copy (hence the poor performance). The key, in either case, is to set IO permissions on the source and destination files using `FileIOPermission` before starting the copy operation.

Here's the relevant excerpt from my code:

```cs
new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, SourcePath).Demand();
new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, DestinationPath).Demand();

if (!NativeCopy.CopyFileEx(SourcePath, DestinationPath,
    new NativeCopy.CopyProgressRoutine(this.CopyProgressHandler), GCHandle.ToIntPtr(hArgs),
    ref pbCancel, flags))
{
    throw new IOException(new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception().Message);
}
```

Hopes this helps. It drove me crazy trying to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to disable the COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE flag for CopyFileEx. I got about 4-5x the speed once that flag was removed.

See MSDN's description of that flag [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx).

> *Progress of the copy is tracked in the target file in case the copy fails... This can significantly slow down the copy operation as the
>   new file may be flushed multiple times during the copy operation.*